# Export or download feature layer table data from arcgis online using python or Arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, export, arcgis-online, download

How would I export feature edit layers or their table data from arcgis online using Python or Arcpy?  I want to download the attributes of a feature edit layer.

Answer (score 1):

With ArcREST you can export/download feature services (plus plenty of other tasks). You can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST) and a [sample blogpost](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2014/10/using-arcrest-to-export-hosted-feature.html) that shows how to do it on an older version, though it should be relatively similar to ArcREST 3.

There are some sample scripts in the repo that should get you started, as well.